# Element goes outside parrent

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem with my CSS.

If you run the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b03esk41/1/) (had to use fiddle because of StackOverflow body limit), and look at the grey background of CASES.

Then you can see that all the content of Cases is nicely inside it the grey area. But if you click on `Casefamily` then you will notice that the `Casefamily` goes outside the grey area. This covers parts of my documentation section.

How can I make the "grey" area expand to its content?

```
<div id="pvCases_d30dcf2a">
  <div class="Cases_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="Controllers_d30dcf2a">
          <input class="search_d30dcf2a" placeholder="Search..">
          <div class="catchWordContainer_d30dcf2a">
            <input class="catchWord_d30dcf2a" placeholder="Catchword">
            <div class="catchWordSuggestion_d30dcf2a"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown_d30dcf2a">
            <div class="selected_d30dcf2a">
              <span> Applicant/Proprietor</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="rightContainer_d30dcf2a">
            <button type="button" id="SaveSearchResult">Save</button>
            <div class="SearchCollection_d30dcf2a">
              <div class="selected_d30dcf2a">
                <span> </span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="SearchCollectionOptions_d30dcf2a">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="CaseTable_d30dcf2a">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>








                <th><span>Case Title</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th><span>Case Number</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th><span>Status</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Case Type</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Family</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Country</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th><span>Catchword</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th><span>Applicant/Proprietor</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Inventor</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Description</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Classes</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Appl. Date</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Reg Date</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a"><span>Abandoned Date</span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  <div class="filter_options_d30dcf2a" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="AtoZ_d30dcf2a">A to Z</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="ZtoA_d30dcf2a">Z to A</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th class="option_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <i class="fa fa-cog cog_d30dcf2a"></i>
                  <div class="cog_options_d30dcf2a">
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <button class="SettingTableOptions_d30dcf2a">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <tr data-content="{&quot;Id&quot;:1,&quot;Title&quot;:&quot;Feed for salmonids&quot;,&quot;Case_Number&quot;:&quot;P47931PC01&quot;,&quot;Status&quot;:&quot;Filed&quot;,&quot;Case_Type&quot;:&quot;Parent&quot;,&quot;Family&quot;:&quot;Test&quot;,&quot;Country&quot;:&quot;Denmark&quot;,&quot;Catchword&quot;:&quot;Web&quot;,&quot;Applicant_x002f_Proprietor&quot;:&quot;P47931PC01&quot;,&quot;Inventor&quot;:&quot;Konfab&quot;,&quot;Description&quot;:&quot;<div class=\&quot;ExternalClass4AF54D6F770C4D72987907C1A07DEA48\&quot;><p>&#8203;Something<br><br></p></div>&quot;,&quot;Classes&quot;:&quot;dunno&quot;,&quot;Appl_x002e_Date&quot;:&quot;2018-06-21T22:00:00Z&quot;,&quot;RegDate&quot;:&quot;2018-06-21T22:00:00Z&quot;,&quot;Abandoneddate&quot;:null,&quot;Picture&quot;:null,&quot;ID&quot;:1}">
                <td>Feed for salmonids</td>
                <td>P47931PC01</td>
                <td>Filed</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Parent</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Test</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Denmark</td>
                <td>Web</td>
                <td>P47931PC01</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Konfab</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="ExternalClass4AF54D6F770C4D72987907C1A07DEA48">
                    <p>&#8203;Something<br><br></p>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">dunno</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">2018-06-21T22:00:00Z</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">2018-06-21T22:00:00Z</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">null</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr data-content="{&quot;Id&quot;:2,&quot;Title&quot;:&quot;case test&quot;,&quot;Case_Number&quot;:&quot;P47931PC02&quot;,&quot;Status&quot;:&quot;Filed&quot;,&quot;Case_Type&quot;:&quot;Parent&quot;,&quot;Family&quot;:&quot;Test&quot;,&quot;Country&quot;:&quot;Denmark&quot;,&quot;Catchword&quot;:&quot;Web&quot;,&quot;Applicant_x002f_Proprietor&quot;:&quot;P47931PC02&quot;,&quot;Inventor&quot;:&quot;Konfab&quot;,&quot;Description&quot;:&quot;<div class=\&quot;ExternalClass3E913664A3344C909C30924BD9212012\&quot;><p>&#8203;Something&#8203;<br></p></div>&quot;,&quot;Classes&quot;:&quot;dunno&quot;,&quot;Appl_x002e_Date&quot;:&quot;2018-06-21T22:00:00Z&quot;,&quot;RegDate&quot;:&quot;2018-06-21T22:00:00Z&quot;,&quot;Abandoneddate&quot;:null,&quot;Picture&quot;:null,&quot;ID&quot;:2}">
                <td>case test</td>
                <td>P47931PC02</td>
                <td>Filed</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Parent</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Test</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Denmark</td>
                <td>Web</td>
                <td>P47931PC02</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">Konfab</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="ExternalClass3E913664A3344C909C30924BD9212012">
                    <p>&#8203;Something&#8203;<br></p>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">dunno</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">2018-06-21T22:00:00Z</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">2018-06-21T22:00:00Z</td>
                <td class="defaultHidden_d30dcf2a">null</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button type="button" class="download_xlsx_d30dcf2a">download as xlsx</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CaseDetails_d30dcf2a" style="display: block;">
    <div class="return_d30dcf2a">
      <span> Cases / </span><span>Feed for salmonids</span>
    </div>
    <div class="CaseDetailContainer_d30dcf2a">
      <ul class="tabs_d30dcf2a group">
        <li><a class="active_d30dcf2a">Case details</a></li>
        <li><a class="">Casefamily</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="box_wrap_d30dcf2a">
        <div class="active_d30dcf2a">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Case Number</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">P47931PC01</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Status</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Filed</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Type</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Parent</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Family</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Test</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Country</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Denmark</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Title</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Feed for salmonids</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Applicant/Proprietor</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">P47931PC01</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Inventor</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Konfab</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Description</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">&#8203;Something</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Classes</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">dunno</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Appl. date</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">21-06-2018</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Reg. Date</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">21-06-2018</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Next Renewal</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Abandoned date</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 left_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class="">Division (subdivision)</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right_container_d30dcf2a">
                  <div class=""></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <img>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Casefamily_d30dcf2a">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  Case No
                </th>
                <th>
                  Name
                </th>
                <th>
                  Applicant/Proprietor
                </th>
                <th>
                  Appl. date
                </th>
                <th>
                  Status
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="status_d30dcf2a Filled_d30dcf2a">
                <td>
                  T62039EU02
                </td>
                <td>
                  Casename
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                  Filed
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="status_d30dcf2a Registered_d30dcf2a">
                <td>
                  T62039EU03
                </td>
                <td>
                  Casename
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                  Registered
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="status_d30dcf2a Pending_d30dcf2a">
                <td>
                  T62039EU04
                </td>
                <td>
                  Casename
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                  Pending
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="status_d30dcf2a Registered_d30dcf2a">
                <td>
                  T62039EU05
                </td>
                <td>
                  Casename
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                  Registered
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="status_d30dcf2a Registered_d30dcf2a">
                <td>
                  T62039EU06
                </td>
                <td>
                  Casename
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                  Registered
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="status_d30dcf2a Registered_d30dcf2a">
                <td>
                  T62039EU07
                </td>
                <td>
                  Casename
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                  Registered
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you viewing the page on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `position: absolute` with `position: relative`, it will expand parent element

```
#pvCases_d30dcf2a .CaseDetails_d30dcf2a .CaseDetailContainer_d30dcf2a .box_wrap_d30dcf2a>div {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Peter it doesn't respect the parent because it is a table, and tables are not responsive. The best solution is to make the parent div to have a CSS attribute of overflow-x : scroll, to enable people to view all the content and to contain you content.

```
#pvCases_d30dcf2a .CaseDetails_d30dcf2a .CaseDetailContainer_d30dcf2a 
.box_wrap_d30dcf2a>div{
 overflow-x : scroll;
}
```